# How to Bind jquery Event with Spring for doing action in one form

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

i am stucking a little concept about controller in Spring. I having a little problem. I made one Entity Class Having Details

```
Contact.java
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

with annotation Tag.
i want to use one form for control all action Ex. Insert , Select , update
i made a view having 
List Box which shows Existing database Record 
And one Form field having two dom element one button

i am using ContactController with annotation binding
I want to perform jquery action with on click List Box it's pass id and retrive the detail and give json or xml response so i can traverse it with jquery and post the data in field.
Similarly i want to bind onClick action for saving or posting data with jquery.

Please help me out with controller

how to load the view mapped with corresponding controller and how to add retrieve method and posting method in controller.. on how to bind jquery event and how to use only one view for all respective actions...
sorry for using bad english ..

Comment: There are too many *"and how to"* phrases in this question.

Comment: only want to know the controller Method List that's all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me you want to post data from your html page to spring controller using jquery.

Create a request in controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "urlMappgin/{dataId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Contact urlMappgin(@PathVariable("dataId") Long dataId) {
    Contact contract = new Contact();
    // TODO do some operation
    return contract;
}
```

in jQuery

```
function urlMappgin(dataId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "urlMappgin/" + dataId,
        success : function(html) {
            // Do Something
        },
        failure : function(errMsg) {
            // Error here
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```